# Retrieve Page Source-javascript - CROSS-DOMAIN

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi I have a project here at work where we need a specific value from another domain I do not have access to change (So I can't do nested iframes). We need to keep Session/Cookie state the same to get the required data from the page as the token changes based on the user on the page. So a server side solution wouldn't work.

What is the best way to go about this, the following is what the page source is in it's entirety. I need to retrieve the AQDV2HqF valuefor

```
(;;);{"<!--":"","token":"AQDV2HqF","expire":1318146839,"":"--><body
onload=document.body.innerHTML=42>"}
```

or to get the whole page source as variable

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are [designed to stop authors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) from reading data from websites they don't control using the visitor's credentials.

So you can't.